# When i test my react build its blank white

Tags: reactjs, typescript, deployment, react-typescript

I'm trying to make my portfolio visible with react but it doesn't appear when i deploy it but when it was in the localhost it was working properly when i open my dev tools this is the error of the test build

[image: Uncaught SyntaxError]

This is the error when i deployed it to github only the css of background and the favicon is detected
[image: Error Output]

and this is the output i want to achieve
[image: Output i want]

this is my package.json file

```
    {
  "homepage": "https://tianmeds.github.io/official-portfolio/",
  "name": "official-portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@ionic/react": "^7.3.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.3",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.16",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.40",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "gsap": "^3.12.2",
    "jquery": "^3.7.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "wow.js": "^1.2.2",
    "wowjs": "^1.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/aos": "^3.0.4",
    "gh-pages": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.15.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your paths for fetching external libraries. you are getting 404s.  This is how it looks like: https://tianmeds.github.io/src//scripts/t.min.js You can see that there are two //. It could be that that is the issue